# Unzip files and save them to a Blob Storage stream

Tags: c#, azure-functions, zip, filestream

My workflow for this proof of concept is:

1. Azure Function App detects a .zip file in blob storage (`Stream inputBlob`)
2. Function app calls my code, which needs to extract the the files and save them individually to the Blob Storage Container `Stream outputBlob`

The code does get the .zip from `inputBlob`, and I can see in the debugger that the `ZipArchive` contains the contents of the .zip. However no files are output, with no errors. What do I need to do to save all of the files to the `outputBlob` stream? I'm sure I'm missing something related to the stream copying.

```
[FunctionName("Name")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("input/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inputBlob,
    [Blob("output/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
    string name, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        using var zip = new ZipArchive(inputBlob);
        
        foreach (var item in zip.Entries)
        {
            using var stream = item.Open();
            stream.CopyTo(outputBlob);
            stream.Close();
        }

        outputBlob.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        outputBlob.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Error at {name}: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side notes: dumping content of ZIP archive in single file (concatenating streams without even paying attention to order) seem to be kind of strange operation... Also very unclear what you expect from `Seek` - may want to add explanation for that line.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe i misworded, i don't want the contents of the zip to be placed in one file. The `outputBlob` is an Azure Blob Storage location, which is where i want all of the files unzipped to. 

The seek is copy paste from another similar function, i don't actually know if i need that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can debug from the VSCode to know where it is causing the issue, for that we need to add `AzureWebJobsStorage` to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in the `local.settings.json` file

Below is the local.settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "unziptools_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=unziptools;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    }
}
```

Similar way as you defined, we need to specify blobtrigger :

```
[BlobTrigger("input-files/{name}", Connection = "cloud5mins_storage")]Stream myBlob
```

Also get the destination container to load the unzip files:

```
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);
```

Below is the sample code for getting the input blob and placing it in the destination storage and container.

```
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("input-files/{name}", Connection = "cloud5mins_storage")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name}");

    string destinationStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationStorage");
    string destinationContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationContainer");

    try{
        if(name.Split('.').Last().ToLower() == "zip"){

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);
            
            using(MemoryStream blobMemStream = new MemoryStream()){

                await myBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(blobMemStream);

                using(ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(blobMemStream))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");

                        //Replace all NO digits, letters, or "-" by a "-" Azure storage is specific on valid characters
                        string valideName = Regex.Replace(entry.Name,@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]","-").ToLower();

                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(valideName);
                        using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        log.LogInformation($"Error! Something went wrong: {ex.Message}");

    }            
}
```

We have a blog where we have detail information about this, thanks to [frankynotes](http://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/02/how-to-unzip-automatically-your-files.html).

Comment: The code provided doesn't work at `await myBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(blobMemStream);`, saying "Stream does not contain a definition for DownloadToStreamAsync". Also its not clear what values `destinationStorage` and `destinationContainer` should be. Are they the same as the BlobPath parameter from the BlobTrigger/Blob attributes?

Comment: With modifications, I was able to get this to work.

Comment: @zakparks31191 Glad, It helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was mostly there for what I needed, but had some non-functional code and checks I didn't need. For documentation, I'm putting the working modified code here:

```
[FunctionName("name")]
public static async Task Run(
    [BlobTrigger("input-blob-container/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inputBlob,
    string name, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        log.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Starting unzip.");

        string destinationStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationStorage");
        string destinationContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationContainer");

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount  = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);

        using ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(inputBlob);
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");
            
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(entry.Name);
            await using var fileStream = entry.Open();
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }

        log.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Finished unzip.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Error at {name}: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

And my local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "destinationStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=azuresitename;AccountKey=;BlobEndpoint=https://azuresitename.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://azuresitename.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://azuresitename.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://azuresitename.file.core.windows.net/",
    "destinationContainer" : "output-blob-container" 
  }
}
```

I added the `destinationStorage` and `destinationContainer` settings via VS Code using the Azure extension (detailed in the video in the accepted answer's blog post).